# iOS - Combine videos to one frame with its own frame

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-processing, audio-processing

I have a serious problem in making photo / video frame in iOS.

The target is to make one video from several videos and several images based on special frame.
[image]

For example, on this frame, the result video will play video 1,2,3 on the background image combined with image 1,2 at a time.

Each video will have different sizes and lengths. I need video combiner.
The main feature is also to combine audios of videos to one.

I have searched several frameworks such as GPUImage framework and AVAssetWriter and so on.

Can anyone help me out to sort out this problem ?

Comment: got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the library [MergeVideos](https://github.com/khoavd-dev/MergeVideos) provides everything you mentioned. In the GitHub example it demonstrates;

> merging multiple video files and multiple image files and text with
>   transition animation:

```
let videoData = VideoData()
videoData.isVideo = true
videoData.asset = AVAsset(url: urlVideo!)

let imageData = VideoData()
imageData.isVideo = false
imageData.image = UIImage(named: "sample-image")

let textData = TextData()
textData.text = "HELLO WORLD"
textData.fontSize = 50
textData.textColor = UIColor.green
textData.showTime = 3 // Second
textData.endTime = 5 // Second
textData.textFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)

KVVideoManager.shared.makeVideoFrom(data: [videoData, imageData], textData: [textData]) { (outputURL, error) in
     if let error = error {
           print("Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
      else {
           if let url = outputURL {
               print("Output video file:\(url)")
           }
     }      
}
```

Although it's not widely used, it looks like definately worth checking out! And it's written in Swift 4 to support a new project.